# XCode and expat XML parser

Tags: c++, xcode

Expat has a .la file for the lib. I am trying to link against it with XCode.

What I have done is to set the target's "Other link flags" to libexpat.la and the "library search path to where the .la file exists.

I get a link error.

Is this an expat installation error or my usage of XCode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to add the library to the "Link Binary with Libraries" build phase under your target. Here's what it looks like in Xcode 3:

[image: Gratuitous Xcode 3 screenshot]

Comment: you are correct. It turns out that .la file contains the list of dylib files needed to link with for expat related code. So I read the .la file, located the, in this case, 3 dylib files as noted in the above image and did away with any references to libexpat.a Thanks for the huge clue.